# Advice on using Shiro to restrict resultset

Tags: java, authorization, shiro

We have an application that allows users to see a list of documents.

Depending on the role of the user and the properties of the document, we want to filter out some of the documents on the list. For example we want to allow the user to view a list with only  the documents that he created and a grey out line for the rest.

At the moment the application executes an SQL SELECT command which returns a list of entries that the user can and cannot see. We want afterwards to restrict this resultset according to the user's permissions and roles. 
Our questions are the following:

- Can this be done via Shiro?
- What is the proper way to place such restrictions when using Shiro? e.g. shall we restrict the list from the start, using the SELECT statement ?

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options:
First since it sounds like you want to display the full list of documents to the user you will still need to query all of them. (though I caution you on this, as that leaks information the user does NOT have access too. For example of user 'jcoder' sees a document titled 'Super Secret Passwords', he knows you have this document. That may or may not matter for your use cases)

If your use case is ONLY "only authors can edit their own documents" then you could just simple username comparison (which I'm guessing you are doing now)

Most use cases are NOT this simple, and require the author as well as administrators, tech writers, etc. access to the resource. So you could assign a set of permissions to the resource.  We can call it `publications:docs:<document_id>:<action>`, or just `docs:<document_id>:<action>`.  Where the `document_id` is some unique document identifier, and `action` what is being done to the resource (in a typical CRUD app they would be create, read, update, delete).
This permissions can be granted to any user and `publications:docs:<document_id>:*` could be granted to the author.  This also allows permissions to be revoked if someone changes position or the document needs to be marked read-only too all users except administrators.

The snippet of code would look something like:

```
if(SecurityUtils.getSubject().isPermitted("publications:docs:":"+ documentId + ":read" ) {
  // do something
}
```

Or you can check them them [all at once](http://shiro.apache.org/static/1.3.2/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/subject/Subject.html#isPermitted-java.lang.String...-).

Your application would need to keep track adding permissions to users.

Take a look at: http://shiro.apache.org/permissions.html

And a similar question: [Java – efficient, database-aware instance-level authorization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786297/java-efficient-database-aware-instance-level-authorization)